# Hyperledger Composer multi-host setup - Error when executing ping

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm, hyperledger-composer

I've been working with Hyperledger Fabric and Composer trying to deploy it over two virtual machines. My work is based on the [Composer multi-org tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org), just extended over the two machines.

**Network Setup:**

Host1: Orderer, Peer1.Org1, Peer2.Org1, CLI

Host2: Peer1.Org2, Peer2.Org2

**Fabric - What works:**

- The peers are up and running;
- They are able to join the channel;
- The anchor peers are updated;
- As a test, I've installed the marbles chaincode on to all peers and I'm able to query successfully;

**Composer - What works:**

- I have 2 connection profiles for both orgs;
- I'm able to install .bna on both hosts without any errors;
- I can start the network;
- I can create the cards and import them on both hosts;

**The issues appear when I try to ping any of the hosts:**

When I ping the network on **host 1**:

```
Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: Peer localhost:8051 has rejected transaction '1ff21ebc89a5d19c2c377f13b10b934168c1dd23d723446b6f51c0bfd79ff346' with code ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE
```

When I ping the network on **host 2**:

```
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '74d166962b282e9f04b17f6d7a8856a1565a257b310aceed5845831b15a710a4', has not been registered
```

These are the logs for **host 1 - peer0**:

```
2018-10-03 11:18:46.704 UTC [lscc] executeInstall -> INFO 03c Installed Chaincode [proa-network] Version [0.0.1] to peer
2018-10-03 11:19:31.081 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 03d Created state database mychannel_proa-network
2018-10-03 11:19:34.521 UTC [cceventmgmt] HandleStateUpdates -> INFO 03e Channel [mychannel]: Handling LSCC state update for chaincode [proa-network]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.546 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 03f Created CouchDB index [selectClaimsByService] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectClaimsByServiceDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.549 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 040 Created CouchDB index [selectInvoicesByPolicy] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectInvoicesByPolicyDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.551 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 041 Created CouchDB index [selectPoliciesByEvaluator] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectPoliciesByEvaluatorDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.554 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 042 Created CouchDB index [selectPoliciesByInsurer] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectPoliciesByInsurerDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.557 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 043 Created CouchDB index [selectPoliciesBySponsor] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectPoliciesBySponsorDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.560 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 044 Created CouchDB index [selectProductsByEvaluator] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectProductsByEvaluatorDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.564 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 045 Created CouchDB index [selectProductsByInsurer] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectProductsByInsurerDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.565 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 046 Created CouchDB index [selectProductsBySponsor] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectProductsBySponsorDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.576 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 047 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [3] with 1 transaction(s)
2018-10-03 11:19:36.964 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 048 [mychannel][d2dade2d] failed to invoke chaincode name:"proa-network" , error: transaction returned with failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '09a1e3cfc2f2d4d297653b30151c9bf0fd8356b324199780fda49c10536551d2', must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED)
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:202
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:141
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:136
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:287
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:501
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:31
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:112
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:923
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1148
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:637
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
2018-10-03 11:19:42.026 UTC [vscc] Validate -> WARN 049 Endorsement policy failure for transaction txid=1ff21ebc89a5d19c2c377f13b10b934168c1dd23d723446b6f51c0bfd79ff346, err: signature set did not satisfy policy
2018-10-03 11:19:42.026 UTC [committer/txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 04a VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId = 1ff21ebc89a5d19c2c377f13b10b934168c1dd23d723446b6f51c0bfd79ff346 returned error: VSCC error: endorsement policy failure, err: signature set did not satisfy policy
2018-10-03 11:19:42.026 UTC [valimpl] preprocessProtoBlock -> WARN 04b Channel [mychannel]: Block [4] Transaction index [0] TxId [1ff21ebc89a5d19c2c377f13b10b934168c1dd23d723446b6f51c0bfd79ff346] marked as invalid by committer. Reason code [ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE]
2018-10-03 11:19:42.067 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 04c Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [4] with 1 transaction(s)
```

**Update: endorsement-policy.json**

```
{
    "identities": [
        {
            "role": {
                "name": "member",
                "mspId": "ManagerMSP"
            }
        },
        {
            "role": {
                "name": "member",
                "mspId": "SponsorMSP"
            }
        }
    ],
    "policy": {
        "2-of": [
            {
                "signed-by": 0
            },
            {
                "signed-by": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}

composer network install --card PeerAdmin@exManager --archiveFile ex-network@0.0.1.bna
cp endorsement-policy.json  /tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json

    echo "Retrieving business network administrator certificates for Manager"
    composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@exManager -u admin -s adminpw -d andreim

    #-------------------
    #-- START NETWORK
    #-------------------

    echo "Starting the business network"
    composer network start -c PeerAdmin@exManager -n ex-network -V 0.0.1 -o endorsementPolicyFile=/tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A andreim -C andreim/admin-pub.pem
```

Another note I would like to make is that after the network starts, 2 containers (probably for chaincode) appear on **host 1**, but none appear on **host 2**. (with a one time exception in which a container for peer0 appeared on **host 2**, almost randomly without any code change).

**Update 2: Logs of peer0 from host 2**

```
.....
2018-10-03 11:15:21.109 UTC [lscc] executeInstall -> INFO 03c Installed Chaincode [proa-network] Version [0.0.1] to peer
2018-10-03 11:18:24.190 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> ERRO 03d [][1bec8b15] simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode name:"lscc"  response status 500 for txid: 1bec8b15b953df0f5e00213916cb092219f949800a0f249ea5f8ef90fcc7eb06
2018-10-03 11:19:34.545 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 03e Created state database mychannel_proa-network
2018-10-03 11:19:34.556 UTC [cceventmgmt] HandleStateUpdates -> INFO 03f Channel [mychannel]: Handling LSCC state update for chaincode [proa-network]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.587 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 040 Created CouchDB index [selectClaimsByService] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectClaimsByServiceDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.589 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 041 Created CouchDB index [selectInvoicesByPolicy] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectInvoicesByPolicyDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.593 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 042 Created CouchDB index [selectPoliciesByEvaluator] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectPoliciesByEvaluatorDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.595 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 043 Created CouchDB index [selectPoliciesByInsurer] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectPoliciesByInsurerDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.598 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 044 Created CouchDB index [selectPoliciesBySponsor] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectPoliciesBySponsorDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.600 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 045 Created CouchDB index [selectProductsByEvaluator] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectProductsByEvaluatorDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.602 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 046 Created CouchDB index [selectProductsByInsurer] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectProductsByInsurerDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.606 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 047 Created CouchDB index [selectProductsBySponsor] in state database [mychannel_proa-network] using design document [_design/selectProductsBySponsorDoc]
2018-10-03 11:19:34.618 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 048 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [3] with 1 transaction(s)
2018-10-03 11:19:42.027 UTC [vscc] Validate -> WARN 049 Endorsement policy failure for transaction txid=1ff21ebc89a5d19c2c377f13b10b934168c1dd23d723446b6f51c0bfd79ff346, err: signature set did not satisfy policy
2018-10-03 11:19:42.027 UTC [committer/txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 04a VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId = 1ff21ebc89a5d19c2c377f13b10b934168c1dd23d723446b6f51c0bfd79ff346 returned error: VSCC error: endorsement policy failure, err: signature set did not satisfy policy
2018-10-03 11:19:42.028 UTC [valimpl] preprocessProtoBlock -> WARN 04b Channel [mychannel]: Block [4] Transaction index [0] TxId [1ff21ebc89a5d19c2c377f13b10b934168c1dd23d723446b6f51c0bfd79ff346] marked as invalid by committer. Reason code [ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE]
2018-10-03 11:19:42.053 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 04c Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [4] with 1 transaction(s)
2018-10-03 11:42:02.836 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 04d [mychannel][f750d0c4] failed to invoke chaincode name:"proa-network" , error: transaction returned with failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '74d166962b282e9f04b17f6d7a8856a1565a257b310aceed5845831b15a710a4', has not been registered
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:202
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:141
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:136
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:287
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:501
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:31
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:112
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:923
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1148
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:637
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
```

Comment: Error trying invoke business network. Error: Peer localhost:8051 has rejected transaction '1ff21ebc89a5d19c2c377f13b10b934168c1dd23d723446b6f51c0bfd79ff346' with code ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE" I faced this error when one of my chaincode container did not spin up. Then, I tried out everything possible but still it didn't work. However, after waiting for about 30 minutes, that chaincode container did spin up. Meaning, it took some time. Are you still facing this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051487/hyperledger-composer-chaincode-container-of-one-of-the-org-not-starting-up

Comment: I guess I'm not the only one who has this problem...

Comment: For host 2, check the connection profile of the admin. This is the card that gets generated when you start the network. So check if the connection profile in the card has the correct details. And I'm still available on the last chat if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your endorsement policy file ? and the commands that use it, probably its something about your policies. At least that it's what the error is pointing.

Comment: I added the endorsement policy. The odd thing is that the chaincode containers for host 2 won't start, as they do on host 1.

Comment: Add the logs of the host 2 containers, they are probably exited, run "docker ps -a" to see them

Comment: Updated question with logs for peer0 on host 2. All the peers are running on host , but suddenly I'm seeing a chaincode container for peer0 on host 2...

Comment: You have this error.
_ERRO 04d [mychannel][f750d0c4] failed to invoke chaincode name:"proa-network" , error: transaction returned with failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '74d166962b282e9f04b17f6d7a8856a1565a257b310aceed5845831b15a710a4', has not been registered_
Maybe you create the admin with a different name ?

Comment: On peer0 on host 1 is getting: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '09a1e3cfc2f2d4d297653b30151c9bf0fd8356b324199780fda49c10536551d2', must be activated (ACTIVATION_REQUIRED).

I've looked through the code and there is no other name for admin in the fabric yamls.

Comment: I thing you are missing your host 2 admin in your start network command _composer network start -c PeerAdmin@exManager -n ex-network -V 0.0.1 -o endorsementPolicyFile=/tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A andreim -C andreim/admin-pub.pem_

I just see one user, in the tutorial in the start network command I can see alice and bob